# A floating div issue

Tags: css, html, floating

I have built a site, but now there needs to be some changes. There is a main picture on the left and a varying bunch of thumbnails aligned on its right floating against the big picture. I want to enlarge the big picture to take up the page, but the little pictures go over the right toolbar, and generally all over the place. I can get them under the main picture as I want to, but they stay to the right with some inexplicibly created margin.

I just want the main picture to cover the page, and the little ones in a line underneath

The site page is here:
http://www.residentialrealtors.co.uk/properties/12-chelsea-cloisters-sloane-aven/

The code affecting these divs is:

```
    .fsrep-main-image {float: left; margin-right: 8px; text-align: center;}
    .fsrep-main-image img { padding: 1px; border: 1px solid #CCC; }
    .fsrep-images {  } 
    .fsrep-aimages {margin-left: 0px;}
    .fsrep-aimage { float: left; width: 100px; height: 80px; padding: 0 10px 5px 0; margin-bottom: 4px; text-align: center; } 
    .fsrep

-aimage img { padding: 3px; border: 1px solid #CCC; }
```

Main image is the big one. Aimage is the small ones ontheir own, and aimages is the small ones as a group.

I hope someone can help. I am going nuts trying to fix this

Answer (score 2):

try adding a clear class to html tag:

```
<div id="fsrep-aimages" class="clear">
```

and then add this to your css(unless you have an equivalent)

```
.clear  { clear: both;}
```

and remove your 362px margin from that div too. this should then move below and stop blowing up in your face.

You are then able to make your large image larger to the full width of the div